# Is it OK to add "TLDR: [summary]" to others' questions?

Tags: discussion, editing

Recently I have made a few edits, adding TLDR section on top of the questions which I consider too long, even after removing unnecessary details. Since I have enough rep, these edits are not peer-reviewed.

I am afraid it might be considered invasive/annoying. I always leave comment like "added tldr, please feel free to edit or remove as you see fit".

Has this topic been discussed on meta here or elsewhere? Is trying to distill OPs question to one or two sentences a good/bad practice?

[Example 1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/154086/feeling-cheated-by-my-organization-due-to-incorrect-details-in-relieving-letter), [example 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/154120/can-a-supervisor-forbid-me-from-being-friends-or-talking-with-a-co-worker)

Comment: Are these new questions? or are they old questions?

Comment: Are you putting an actual "tl;dr: [summary]" at the top or just summarising the key question of the post? I would read the former as rather rude especially considering the latter is just about as much work and makes for a more readable question.

Comment: @Lilienthal here are examples https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/154086/feeling-cheated-by-my-organization-due-to-incorrect-details-in-relieving-letter and https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/154120/can-a-supervisor-forbid-me-from-being-friends-or-talking-with-a-co-worker

Comment: Would it be okay if you use the work summary instead?  I would probably be a little bit annoyed if someone implied my post was too long and has not to be read.

Comment: @guest OK now i understand attitude! I didn't mean to insult OP. English-as-second-language is hard. "TLDR" ~ "summary" for my ear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion: yes and no.

Summarising the key question in a post is **always** recommended and while we encourage the OP to include it or make the question concise/readable enough that a summary isn't required, we do get plenty of long posts that can be rambling in nature.

One of the most common edits I make and probably the second most common after typo fixes on the site in general is to make questions more readable. Very often that means **identifying or adding the core question**.

What I would **not recommend** is to add that summary with an actual "tl;dr". Given the literal meaning it can still be taken the wrong way but more importantly there's just no reason to include it. If you add a single sentence as its own paragraph at the top or end of a post that will automatically add emphasis and be taken as the summary or key question. If you want, you can emphasize further with bold formatting or by adding a horizontal rule before the rest of the post. In addition, while it's pretty common netspeak at this point, there are still people who would be confused by the term, especially those not familiar with English language internet slang.

So **tl;dr**: **summarize or emphasize the core question** rather than adding actual "tl;dr" blocks.